# Custom CUPS spool directory per printer

Tags: cups

Is there any way to have a custom spool folder for a printer in CUPS?
e.g. instead of /var/spool/cups/ /var/spool/cups/printername/

Comment: while there are printer(group)-specific temporary files, /var/spool isn't really just things that cups could "assign" to a single printer. I'm not sure, but I don't think what you ask for here is trivial to implement without rewriting parts of cups. Now, maybe you're asking this because there's some specific problem you want to solve for which this seems to be a solution – if you could tell us about that, maybe we could answer with that in mind.